# Adding an associated object to URLRequest

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to make an extension on URLRequest that allows it to be initialized with an associated object and then be able to retrieve that object later on to know if that request "belongs" to that object. My first attempt was:

```
class User {
    init(_ id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
    let id: Int
}

private var userKey: UInt8 = 0
extension URLRequest {
    init(url: URL, user: User) {
        self.init(url: url)
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &userKey, user, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }

    var user: User? {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &userKey) as? User
    }
}

let user1 = User(3)
let req1 = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "google.com")!, user: user1)
print(req1.user?.id ?? -1) // prints -1
```

So I realized that it's because in swift 3, URLRequest is not a struct. So am I correct in assuming that you cannot use `objc_setAssociatedObject` on a struct type successfully? The docs for `objc_setAssociatedObject` specify `Any` as the parameter type so unsure, but would make sense I guess, or am I not seeing something and this is possible?

Second attempt: Instead of doing

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &userKey, user, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
```

I did

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self.url, &userKey, user, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
```

This works. Because I assume url is a reference type. But, then the problem is that url is also mutable, so later on someone can do `request.url = blah` and I lose the associated `user` object.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Churr!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to add a variable to hold the associated object - but you can't do that with extensions.

You **can** do it by creating a custom class based on `URLRequest` - anything you don't change remains exactly as it was, but you can add as many variables as you need.